# Using Malloc to allocate memory to STL list?

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, malloc, new-operator

I am trying to allocate memory to stl list using malloc. I works fine with **new** as below:

```
typedef pair<int, int> iPair;
list< pair<int, int> > *adj;
adj = new list<iPair> [V];
```

But throws segmentation fault if I use **malloc** instead of new.

```
adj=(list<iPair> *)malloc(sizeof(list<iPair>)*V);
```

Why **malloc** cannot be used to allocate memory to STL containers?

Comment: Because there is more to the construction of a `list<iPair>`  (or an instance of any class with a non-trivial constructor) than allocating memory for it using `malloc()` and casting the result.   Operator `new` takes care of the additional needs that `malloc()` doesn't.   In your code, subsequent usage of `adj` that assumes it actually points at a properly constructed collection of `list<iPair>`  (which it doesn't) will have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `malloc` comes from C and C has no idea of classes and thus no concept of constructors. `new` allocates the memory and calls the appropriate constructor, `malloc` only allocates the memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it's done a bit differently. Basically you need to make sure the memory you use is initialized. `malloc` returns uninitialized memory though.

You can use placement new to initialize the list object in a memory location of your choice. Just be extra careful when deleting the object:

**Allocation**

```
void* memory = std::malloc(sizeof(list<iPair>) * V); // uninitialized memory

if (memory == nullptr)
{
    // allocating the memory may fail
    throw std::bad_alloc();
}
list<pair<int, int>> *adj = static_cast<list<pair<int, int>> *>(memory);

size_t initializedCount = 0;

// constructors may throw, so we need to make sure
// already initialized objects are freed in case this happend
try
{
    while(initializedCount < V)
    {
        adj = new (adj[initializedCount])list<pair<int, int>>();
        ++initializedCount;
    }
}
catch(...)
{
    // make sure destructors are called for objects initialized already
    for (size_t i = 0; i < initializedCount; ++i)
    {
        (adj +i)->~list<pair<int, int>>();
    }
    
    // free the memory we allocated ourselves & rethrow
    std::free(memory);
    throw;
}
```

**Deletion**

```
// release the memory
for (size_t i = 0; i < V; ++i)
{
    (adj + i)->~list<pair<int, int>>();
}

// free the memory we allocated ourselves & rethrow
std::free(memory);
```